# Can I use a hash of fields instead of direct field comparison to simplify comparison of records?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am integrating between 4 data sources:

```
InternalDeviceRepository
ExternalDeviceRepository
NightlyDeviceDeltas
MidDayDeviceDeltas
```

Changes flow into the **InternalDeviceRepository** from the other three sources.
All sources eventually are transformed to have the definition of

```
FIELDS
=============
IdentityField
Contract
ContractLevel
StartDate
EndDate
ContractStatus
Location
```

IdentityField is the PrimaryKey, Contract Key is a secondary Key only if a match exists, otherwise a new record needs to be created.

Currently I compare all the fields in a WHERE clause in SQL Statements and also in a number of places in SSIS packages.  This creates some unclean looking SQL and SSIS packages.

I've been mulling computing a hash of ContractLevel, StartDate, EndDate, ContractStatus, and Location and adding that to each of the input tables.  This would allow me to use a single value for comparison, instead of 5 separate ones each time.

I've never done this before, nor have I seen it done.  Is there a reason that it should be used, or is that a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a valid approach. Consider to introduce a calculated field with the hash and index on it.

You may  use either [CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) function or write your own hash function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMyLongHash(@data VARBINARY(MAX))
RETURNS VARBINARY(MAX)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @res VARBINARY(MAX) = 0x
    DECLARE @position INT = 1, @len INT = DATALENGTH(@data)

    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @res = @res + HASHBYTES('MD5', SUBSTRING(@data, @position, 8000))
        SET @position = @position+8000
        IF @Position > @len 
          BREAK
    END
    WHILE DATALENGTH(@res) > 16 SET @res= dbo.GetMyLongHash(@res)
    RETURN @res
END
```

which will give you 16-byte value - you may take all the 16 bytes as Guid, or only first 8-bytes as bigint and compare it.

Adapt the function in your way - to accept string as parameter or even all the your fields instead of varbinary

**BUT**

- be careful with strings casing, datetime formats
- if using CHECKSUM - check also other fields, checksum produces dublicates
- avoid using 4-byte hash result on relaively big table

Comment: Interesting approach - how would you apply this to multiple fields? Thanks.

Comment: You may always concatenate fields together and pass the result to function